# Xcode bundle ids of free and commercial apps do not compile properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a free version with ads and a commercial ad-free version.

Now, I compiled my free app and submitted it with no problems.

Next, I copied my app folder, removed the ad-code and changed the bundle id
to match the commercial version.

When I change the bundle ID, the app does not compile, it stars running but
immediately says "Finished running app..."

As soon as I return my prev bundle id, it runs ok.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Check your scheme, and make sure you *never* have both Xcode projects open at the same time.  Xcode never enjoyed twins.

Comment: @CodaFi, a simple solution would be to just rename the project to avoid this "twins" issue, no?

Comment: Actually, if the project truly is a duplicate, Xcode will still play devil's advocate *occasionally*

Comment: You should have two targets in one project, not two separate projects.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your schemes may be bad. Try this:

1) Change your bundle identifier

2) Rename the project by clicking on the project name (at the top of the project navigator) pressing enter, inputting a new name, and allowing Xcode to proceed with its automated renaming process (this may be optional, not sure if Xcode cares honestly if two projects have the same name and are built on same device/simulator... but just to be safe...)

2) Click the project's drop-down menu (next to the "stop" button) and click on "manage schemes"

3) Select all schemes, press delete, and then press "delete" on popup

4) Click on "Autocreate Schemes Now" to create new schemes

5) Do a clean (product menu -> clean), build, and try running the project again

Good luck.

Comment: thx but non of those suggestions work, renamed the schemes, the project, changed the bundle id, nothing worked so far

Comment: Is the free version also installed on said device/simulator already?

Comment: Is the bundle display name exactly the same? If so, have you tried changing it to see if this makes a difference?